Identify the movie with actress dies taking revenge of her friend's death
Hollywood movie in which actress has telekinetic powers, she dies in the process of taking revenge on people who are responsible for her friend's death. Her boyfriend is dreaming of her exactly one year after her death at midnight.
In his dream, she breaks like a glass.
I watched it in DVD late 90s, some details about movie I remember is that she has something on her shoulder which beats like a heart. 
Her friend jumps off from a college building.
There's a swimming pool scene, she kills one woman by shattering her spectacles with her telekinetic power.
Sorry, I don't remember it fully.

You're looking for The Rage: Carrie 2 (so it's kind of a duplicate of this one), but thank you for improving the question!

@Walt Thanks, this is the movie, I'm searching for.

No problem. I put up the answer anyway since the 2 questions are quite different.

You're looking for The Rage: Carrie 2 from 1999.

After the suicide of her only friend, Rachel Lang has never felt more on the outside. The one person who reached out to her, Jessie Ryan, also happens to be part of the popular crowd that lives to torment outsiders like her. However, Rachel has something else that separates her from the rest, secret amazing powers to move things with her mind. Sue Snell, the only survivor of Carrie White's rampage 23 years ago, may hold the key to helping Rachel come to terms with her awesome, but unwanted powers. But as Rachel slowly learns to trust, a terrible trap is being laid for her, and making her angry could prove to be deadly.

All the scenes you mentioned are there. Here's the trailer:



